# Is it secure if I store a sha1 password and a userID in secure flag & https Cookies?

Tags: security, cookies

I'm doing a connection system for my users. So I decided to use Cookies to store the User ID and the password (in sha1). But I have one question. If a random user gets the value of both cookies and their names, can he creates them with for example a js function and get into the account?

Comment: It is absolutely unsafe to store the user credentials in cookies. cookies are simply some text files that are stored on local machine and they are easily accessible to hackers.

Comment: @Sparrow but the password is encrypted. My question is if someone artificially create them on his computer by using "inspect code". Can he gets into a user account ?

Comment: A few points: the secure flag for the cookie, means that the 'transmission' of cookie will not happen as plain text and it will be transferred as HTTPS. So, the transmission is protected, but the local storage is not. The Password being hashed, is still not bullet proof. There are some sort of dictionary attacking tools that can find the unhashed string for hashed strings. The way they work, is that they have a huge table with strings as plain text and their hashed strings. These tables contain common passwords.

Comment: See the following posts for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503802/client-login-how-to-store-credentials-securely-on-client-side

Comment: Also see this one: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: It's not safe, and there should be no reason to do that ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it secure if I store a sha1 password and a userID in secure flag &
>   https Cookies?

No.

I suppose you want to know why?  First, define "safe."  What threat are you trying to mitigate?

Once the credentials are hashed, there's no way to get the plaintext back.  Since you can't render the hashed string back to plaintext then we can assume that the intent is to compare them to the same hashed string held at the server, yes?  That's awesome if the threat you want to mitigate is somebody discovering the password and user ID *and* you use something like `SHA256` instead of `SHA1`.

But if the threats you want to mitigate include replay attack or session hijacking, then these are no better than any other fixed string.  In fact they are worse.  If the user is obliged to provide their password for each HTTPS request it sucks for them but at least the app can throttle login attempts and foil a brute force attack.  If the credentials are hashed and exchanged in cookies, then they are exposed to adversaries and if obtained can be subjected to brute force cracking or looked up in a rainbow table so on net sending the credentials back out, even encrypted or hashed, kinda sucks.

The question doesn't mention salt or session keying.  An adversary will look at the cookies to see identical values are returned over multiple sessions.  To prevent replay attack you'd need to append a nonce before hashing to act as a salt so the hashed string changes each time.  But it doesn't solve the problem of sending a transformed credential pair outside of control of your own server or that this is far  worse than just using a long random string for the same purpose.

Furthermore, the hash of the credentials doesn't time out until and unless the user changes their password - at which point it tells an adversary that the user just changed their password which is a great piece of info with which to social engineer the IT support person who does password recovery.  "Hi, I just changed my password and locked the account.  Can you reset it?  Employee ID?  Well if I had access I could look it up.  Can you just reset it?  I'm really me.  How else would anyone I know I just changed it?"

The support person would never guess the answer to that question is "because Victor's app design told me it was just changed" and might just reset it for the adversary.  But if the session is kept alive by a session cookie or a triparte login token then the unique string representing that user's session mitigates all of the threats discussed so far:

- An attacker can't reverse it or crack it to discover credentials because they aren't in there.
- It can't be used for session replay since it is generated to be unique for each session.
- It expires within a short period of time so it can't be resurrected from browser cache or history.

But rather than answer the question as asked, I'd like to answer the question "Is there an authoritative source for comprehensive web application security best practices?"  That's a much easier question to answer *and* it potentially answers your initial question if you follow through with the required study.

Please see: [Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP)](https://www.owasp.org/).

In particular, please see the [Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) and the [Authentication Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet) as these cover much of what you are trying to do here.

OWASP periodically analyzes all reported breaches for a recent period and then publishes the Top 10 Vulnerability List based on the root causes that showed up most often during the sample period.  When I QA new web sites on behalf of clients they almost always have several of the defects in OWASP's Top 10 list.  If as a developer or web site development company you want to stand head and shoulders above the crowd and get a lot of repeat business, all you need to do is make sure the site you deliver doesn't have any defects in OWASP's list.  The question suggests any application built as proposed would have at least 4 or 5 defects from the OWASP Top 10 so that's an aspirational goal for now.  Aim high.